# Help with an inequality in Cazenave's book "Semilinear Schrodinger equations"

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, real-analysis

I'm reading Cazenave's book "Semilinear Schrodinger equations" and I found this inequality at page 84
$$\vert\vert u_1\vert^\alpha u_1-\vert u_2\vert^\alpha u_2\vert\vert\leq C (\vert u_1\vert^\alpha+\vert u_2\vert^\alpha)\vert u_1-u_2\vert$$
where $u_1, u_2$ are complex-valued functions.
Any suggestion for proving it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what norms you are using, but this inequality holds pointwise (with a uniform constant), so it easily generalize to any reasonable norm.

So we show the pointwise version: let $z_1$ and $z_2\in\mathbb C$. We show

$$||z_1|^\alpha z_1-|z_2|^\alpha z_2| \le C(|z_1|^\alpha+|z_2|^\alpha)|z_1-z_2|.$$

Define $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb C$, given by

$$f(t)=|z_1+t(z_2-z_1)|^\alpha (z_1+t(z_2-z_1)).$$

By the FTC, the LHS is

$$ |f(1)-f(0)|\le \left| \int_0^1 f'(t)dt \right|$$

so we are let to bound $f'(t)$. By the product rule it has two terms: the first one is:

$$ |z_1+t(z_2-z_1)|^\alpha (z_2-z_1) $$

which is bounded by

$$ (|z_1|+|z_2-z_1|)^\alpha |z_2-z_1|\le C(|z_1|^\alpha +|z_2|^\alpha)|z_1-z_2|.$$

The other term is

$$ \left( \frac{d}{dt}|z_1+t(z_2-z_1)|^\alpha \right) (z_1+t(z_2-z_1)). $$

The second factor is bounded by $C(|z_1|+|z_2|)$. The first factor is, by the chain rule,

$$ \alpha|z_1+t(z_2-z_1)|^{\alpha-1} \frac{d}{dt}|z_1+t(z_2-z_1)|\le C(|z_1|^{\alpha-1}+|z_2|^{\alpha-1})|z_2-z_1|. $$

Multiply them together and you get the same bound

$$ C(|z_1|^\alpha +|z_2|^\alpha)|z_1-z_2| $$

as above. Hence this is the bound for $|f'(t)|$. You integrate from 0 to 1 to obtain the inequality.

Comment: in your proof you are assuming that $\alpha\geq 1$, isn't it?